# How to filter text with several parentheses in bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement, sed

I have a bash script that creates a text file and then manipulates it with sed commands. However, on occasion there is a line which contains multiple parentheses.

For example:

```
fileInfo:    (2014) (b2b) (analog) (digital) (some-text)
```

This line could be as few a 1 set of () but usually at least 2. In the end I am only interested in extracting the last set of ()

```
fileInfo:    (some-text)
```

I can get it to work if there is a set number of (), but not when it varies from each file.

Until I encountered a file that had more than 2 sets of () the following has worked:

```
if grep -q "textInfo:   (.*) (.*)" "$TXT"; then
  SG=`egrep textInfo "$TXT" | sed "s/.*) (//"| sed "s/)$//"`
else
  SG=`egrep textInfo "$TXT" | sed "s/.* (//"| sed "s/)$//"`
fi
```

Comment: This is rather trivial.  Make some effort.  You'll find numerous such examples.

Comment: I have been searching, and had a suitable example been found I would not have posted.

Comment: @GregKuhn, show us what you've tried.

Comment: @GregKuhn it's easier if you rephrase it as "Delete all text up until the last ("

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this gnu `sed` command,

```
sed -r 's/^([^ ]+)( )+.*\((.*)\)/\1\2(\3)/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'fileInfo: (2014) (b2b) (analog) (digital) (some-text)' | sed -r 's/^([^ ]+)( )+.*\((.*)\)/\1\2(\3)/g'
fileInfo: (some-text)
```

- `^([^ ]+)` -Matches and stores one or more characters which is not to be a space and stored it into the first group.(Once it finds a space, sed stops fetching the characters)
- `( )+` - Matches one or more space characters and stored it into the second group.Once the sed finds a character which is not to space character, it suddenly stops fetching.
- `.*\(` - Matches any character upto the literal `(`. Normally sed matches the last `(`, if a line contains more than one `(`.
- `(.*)\)` - Fetches the characters inside the last `()` brackets and stored it into the third group.
- `\1\2(\3)` - Finally using back reference, sed replaces the whole line with these fetched groups.

Comment: Works perfectly! Now I need to break it down to understand what its doing. Thanks

Comment: do you want me to explain?

Comment: If you have the time and are inclined to do so. Otherwise I will try on my own

Comment: Thanks. This will be most helpful with additional parts of the script when I get to that part.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can do this

I am not an expert in sed but probably this code catches the text in last paranthesis. You only need to add the other fixed text that you need.

```
sed -n '/\(([^)]+)\)$/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using BASH regex:

```
s='fileInfo:    (2014) (b2b) (analog) (digital) (some-text)'
[[ "$s" =~ ^([^:]+:).*(\([^()]*\))[^()]*$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fileInfo: (some-text)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/:.*(/:(/' file
```

Delete everything from `:` to the last `(` and then replace the `:` and `(`.

N.B. `.*` is greedy and always aims for the longest match.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/([^ ]+ +).*(\(.*)/\1 \2/' file
fileInfo:     (some-text)
```